# Is the "Japanese whiskey" in the picture a real brand, and if so what is its full name?

Tags: whiskey, whisky

The attached image is a screen capture from a [TV show](https://www.ardmediathek.de/video/tatort/tatort-vier-jahre-oder-team-koeln/das-erste/Y3JpZDovL2Rhc2Vyc3RlLmRlL3RhdG9ydC9hNmI3MzViYS0wYzhhLTRhMzYtYjE4Yy1jMjIwN2RhYzA1NWE/) (@ ~00:12:30).

[image]

Unfortunately, it flashed for only a fraction of a second, and that's all that was shown.

Though the label on the bottle says "Japanese whiskey," I cannot identify any brand of Japanese whiskey that matches this label.

(This, in itself, does not mean much, though; I am pretty ignorant about Japanese whiskeys, in general.)

From the little Japanese I know, I thought that the character shown along the label's right edge was 神 (= かみ = gods), but I could not find any Japanese whiskey brand online that has this character on its label.

On the other hand, it is quite possible that this is not a real Japanese whiskey brand at all, but rather a made-for-TV prop.

Can anyone recognize this label, and if so, what is the brand?

(For what it's worth, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mGDA.jpg) is a larger version of the same image.)

Comment: Can you add a link to the TV movie?

Comment: @KenGraham: done.  The show is in German.  I don't know how to provide a link that is cued to the moment when the bottle appears on the screen, but I added the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, kjo. Do not know if it is going to help, but hopefully.

Comment: Would it make sense in the context of the movie if it was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yūrei ?

Comment: @David: that's not whisky, that's a beer! ;-P https://beerconnoisseur.com/review/judges-review-94-rating-yurei-arches-brewing

Answer (score 7):

At 12:12 you have another shot, where you better see the shape of the bottle. together with the black cap in your screenshot maybe that rings a bell for someone who is into whiskey?

At 12:15 little more of the label, there it looks more like ...OREI than ...UREI. (or like David says in the comments, it could mean [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yūrei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABrei), but can't find any brand with that name either)

I wasn't able to download the video, but maybe if you watch it in high quality you can see more details?

My personal guess is, they took a cheap bottle from a german super market and relabeled by the movie company to avoid legal issues. or they have a warehouse full of movie requisites and took the one that looks most like a whiskey bottle. surest way would be to ask the movie company.

At 1:28:26 it says:

> Requisite: Dirk Breitenbach Stephanie Moldrings